# How do I auto copy the entries in different sheets for the matching cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have complex scenario I'm not sure if this can be done using excel, I have 3 sheets **Sheet1, sheet2, sheet3,** I want to copy entries from sheet1 to other sheet based on following condition.

**Sheet 1**

[image]

**Sheet2** should be populated automatically with following data

[image]

**Sheet3** should be populated automatically with following data

[image]

Comment: use `XLOOKUP` or https://exceljet.net/index-and-match (if ur excel is not version 365).

Comment: If you want it to be automatically you need a VBA solution or Office 365 or you create a large range containing formulas to cover the number of occurances.If you except VBA solution, please include VBA tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

VLOOKUP can be used to find the matches

Link below has more information about the lookups and other formulas to find the matches

https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/vlookup.html

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/07/17/excel-vlookup-tutorial-beginner/